# Contents not showing properly on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to add buttons to a table view cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell")

    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    let view2: UIView = UIView()
    view2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 100)

    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    cell?.contentView.addSubview(view2)

    prifilebtn = UIButton()
    prifilebtn.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: (view.bounds.height-60)/2, width: 60, height: 60)
    prifilebtn.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    prifilebtn.clipsToBounds = true
    prifilebtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    view2.addSubview(prifilebtn)

    return cell!
}
```

The `prifilebtn` is not showing properly on view which i added to the cell. I am trying to do this programatically. I don' t know what's causing the problem - any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: This is not the right way to add subviews to a cell. Subclass `UITableViewCell` and dequeue that custom cell.

Comment: but this should work right?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you are getting?

Comment: No, it will not work. You dequeue cells, e.g. reuse them, and you always add new UIViews and UIButtons as subview to them, so you end up with a large amount of subviews in your cell, expecially when you have a large amount of data in your table and the user starts scrolling around. Check one of the million tutorials about UITableViewCell subclassing here or anywhere in the web.

Comment: its should display same on all sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can customise the UI of your cell. The best way is to [subclass UITableViewCell and there are many tutorials on how to do so](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/).

However if you want to avoid subclassing when updating the layout and frames for a cell and its subviews, I believe it is better to handle on the callback for the method:

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
            willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```